# Why doesn't Bootstrap button dropdown work on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It looks like even the [bootstrap demo here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) doesn't work on iOS. You don't seem to be able to select an item from it on iPhone or iPad.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: The bootstrap demo you mention does work on my iPhone. Can you post some code so we can see what your issue might be?

Comment: Thanks @WesleyMurch for re-posting that for me. I apologize for the incorrect usage of an answer, still a newbie here.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in the 2.1.1 version: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4550

Answer (score 9):

There is a quick fix as noted in many of the issue comments on github:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2975#issuecomment-8670606

add this script just before your close html tag:

```
$('body').on('touchstart.dropdown', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

I have tested the above method on both ios5 and 6. It works like a charm

---

If you wish to modify the bootstrap javascript you could, instead of the fix above, remove touchstart.dropdown.data-api from the html binding for clearMenus near the bottom of the file.

just change this

```
$('html')
  .on('click.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
```

to this

```
$('html')
  .on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
```

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: I'm still facing this issue in iOS 7..I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4 & jQuery 1.11.3..Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a customize jquery in your file.If you want to use that then use:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group lt category_bg">
    <p>Adults</p>
    <button class="btn btn-large" data-toggle="dropdown"><cite>0</cite> <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
      <li id='adult_0' onClick="flight_user(this.id)"><a href="#" >0</a></li>
      <li id='adult_1' onClick="flight_user(this.id)"><a href="#" >1</a></li>
      <li id='adult_2' onClick="flight_user(this.id)"><a href="#" >2</a> </li>
      <li id='adult_3' onClick="flight_user(this.id)"><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li id='adult_4' onClick="flight_user(this.id)"><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>


 <script>
    function flight_user(selected){
    var value = jQuery("#" + selected).find('a').text();
    jQuery("#" + selected).parent().parent().find('cite').html(value);
    }

</script>
```

I can give you live demo for this if you want

Comment: actully bootstrap have given only dropdown not the selectable dropdown.I also face the same problem bt didnt get solution so i did it in this way

Comment: That answer doesn't sound right. I have events attached to the anchor tags and they work on desktop. You're suggesting to set extra event handlers to list items. Do you know why?

Comment: see i did it in this way so i give you the answer.IF you found some better way then its very gud.Do post the answer if you solve that that could be better for me :-)

Comment: I think we can not do this only with the bootstrap js.We have to have add some extra code for this.

Comment: I know that I must add custom jQuery code to handle the event. My event handler was assigned to the anchor tags using addEvent/addEventListener functions. However if this was an event handler issue then the dropdown should also fail on desktop but it doesn't. Anyway I did try your suggestion with no result.

Comment: who is downvote ?? if i will show the working demo then.....if you knw the answer then please do share with us else stay out of it

Answer (score 0):

This script solve this problem. Just add this code

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.your-drop-down-link', function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            if(event.handled !== true) {

                if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('open') ) {
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                }else{
                    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
                }

                event.handled = true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
       });
```

Comment: For good answer it would be good to add some explanation what the code does.