# Bootstrap 3 - Button dropdowns do not work on IPhone

Tags: javascript, c#, iphone, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been scouring the internet looking for a solution to this issue and apparently it should have been fixed in Bootstrap 3. But, it isn't.

Basically, on a site I am developing we have several drop down buttons that form a search panel on the site. On desktop and other devices, when the user clicks on a field, a menu is produced allowing them to make a selection. This works perfectly on desktop and Android but on Iphone (tested on IPhone 5) the menu will trigger once but then no other menus will trigger at all.

[image: Tour Finder]

The code I am using for each section is as follows (There is some razor code in there as well but just assume that is outputting options):

```
<div class="col-lg-5ths col-sm-3" id="tour-type-selection">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" placeholder="@(Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("Tourfinder.Display.Type"))" class=" btn btn-default tf_option tour_finder" data-toggle="dropdown" data-text="@(Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.Type"))" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-inactive="fa-arrow-circle-down" data-active="fa-check">
                            <i class="fa @(type.Count() > 0 ? "fa-check greenTick" : "fa-arrow-circle-down") pull-right"></i>
                            @Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.Type")
                        </button>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu tourtype-menu">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="Trip_Type" @(type.Contains("0") ? "checked='checked'" : string.Empty) value="0">All Tours</label>
                            </div>
                            @foreach (IPublishedContent item in categories)
                            {
                                var value = item.GetPropertyValue<string>("categoryId");
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="Trip_Type" @(type.Contains(value) ? "checked='checked'" : string.Empty) value="@value" />@item.Name</label>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5ths col-sm-3" id="tour-date-selection">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" placeholder="@(Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.Date"))" class="btn btn-default tf_option tour_finder" data-toggle="dropdown" data-text="@(Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.Date"))" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-inactive="fa-calendar" data-active="fa-check"><i class="fa @(startDate != string.Empty && endDate != string.Empty ? "fa-check greenTick" : "fa-calendar") pull-right"></i>@(Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.Date"))</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu datepicker-menu">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                                <label for="dateFrom" class="">@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.DateFrom")</label>
                                <input type="text" name="Date_From" id="dateFrom" title="Eg. yyyy/MM/dd" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" @(startDate != string.Empty ? "value=" + startDate : string.Empty) />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                                <label for="dateTo" class="">@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.DateTo")</label>
                                <input type="text" name="Date_To" id="dateTo" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" @(endDate != string.Empty ? "value=" + endDate : string.Empty) />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5ths col-sm-3" id="tour-duration-selection">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" placeholder="@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.Duration") " class="btn btn-default tf_option tour_finder" data-toggle="dropdown" data-text="@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.Duration")" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-inactive="fa-clock-o">
                            <i class="fa @(duration.Count() > 0 ? "fa-check greenTick" : "fa-clock-o") pull-right"></i>@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Display.Duration")
                        </button>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu tourduration-menu">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" @(duration.Contains("1") ? "checked='checked'" : string.Empty) name="Trip_Duration" value="1" />@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Value.Duration.DayTours")</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" @(duration.Contains("2") ? "checked='checked'" : string.Empty) name="Trip_Duration" value="2" />@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Value.Duration.2-3Days")</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">   
                                     <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" @(duration.Contains("3") ? "checked='checked'" : string.Empty) name="Trip_Duration" value="3" />@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Value.Duration.4-6Days")</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" @(duration.Contains("4") ? "checked='checked'" : string.Empty)  name="Trip_Duration" value="4" />@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("TourFinder.Value.Duration.7+Days")</label>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
```

As you can see I am just using the standard bootstrap code to implement the drop downs so can anyone explain why this is not working on IPhone as I have the entire Bootstrap library in place:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns
```

The site in question can be found here:

http://icelandmountainguides.axumdev.com

NB.  I have tried the touchstart fix described in this thread for Bootstrap 2 but this does not seem to do anything

[Why doesn't Bootstrap button dropdown work on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190783/why-doesnt-bootstrap-button-dropdown-work-on-ios)